# TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str when parsing lists

Tags: python, arrays, list, error-handling, raspberry-pi

This is my code:

```
import requests
import json

res = requests.get("http://transport.opendata.ch/v1/connections? 
from=Baldegg_kloster&to=Luzern&fields[]=connections/from/prognosis/departure")

parsed_json = res.json()

print(parsed_json['connections']['from']['prognosis'])
"departure"
```

However, if I run it i get the following errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/pi/Desktop/Matura/v7/v7_test.py", line 10, in <module>
print(parsed_json['connections']['from']['prognosis'])
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

I've looked at other similar Questions , but I didn't find a solution
I am new to coding, so I have no Idea where the problem could be.

Comment: what is inside of `res.json()` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First lets check the contents of `parsed_json`.

```
{'connections': [{'from': {'prognosis': {'departure': '2018-08-04T11:24:00+0200'}}}, {'from': {'prognosis': {'departure': '2018-08-04T11:53:00+0200'}}}, {'from': {'prognosis': {'departure': '2018-08-04T12:22:00+0200'}}}, {'from': {'prognosis': {'departure': None}}}]}
```

If you see the output, the children of `connections` is not a `str` but a `list`. You can't access an element in a list with a `str`, that's why you are getting that error.

So change

`print(parsed_json['connections']['from']['prognosis'])`

to

`print(parsed_json['connections'][0]['from']['prognosis'])`

You can change the `0` to the `index` of the element you want.

Answer (score 0):

You have to parse the json like this based on your response,

```
import requests
import json

res = requests.get("http://transport.opendata.ch/v1/connections?\
from=Baldegg_kloster&to=Luzern&fields[]=connections/from/prognosis/departure")

parsed_json = res.json()

for item in parsed_json['connections']:
    print(item['from']['prognosis']['departure'])
```